# Accessing data from a parent repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following setup (trimmed down):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptParent" OnItemDataBound="rptParent_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <a href="#<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "eventnumber" )%><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productid" )%>" class="toggle">Attendees</a>

          <asp:Repeater ID="rptChild" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptChild_ItemDataBound">
               <HeaderTemplate>
                   <div id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.Parent.Parent, "DataItem.hiddenEventID")%>'class="attendees">
               </HeaderTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   [Stuff in here]
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What I'm trying to do is (in rptChild repeater) to get some dataitems from it's parent (rptParent). I've tried using the Container.Parent.Parent but no data is ever displayed?

Can anyone see what it is that I'm doing wrong or help in any way?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: You must redesign your datasource A so that the object bind to the rptParent will se the datasource of the rptChild inside the rptParent_ItemDataBound event to another object inside the A datasource.

Answer (score 0):

If Parent.Parent doesn't work try using NamingContainer, for example in your onitemdatabound method :

```
((RepeaterItem)e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer).DataItem
```

Or to give you an example more like your scenario:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer, "DataItem.hiddenEventID")%>' class="attendees">
           </HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm a little unsure of this code in so much as to how do I actually reference the fields that I'm after?

Comment: Does it work for you when you use the second example I provided? This should essentially be pluggable into your existing code replacing your parent.parent code.

Comment: No I'm getting nothing. It's even stripping out the equals sign directly after the id which is really confusing me!

Comment: Might be nothing but I've edited my code, you need a space before the class declaration. try that.

Comment: Hello. Still nothing I'm afraid. I'm not even sure this is possible!

Comment: It is possible, I've done it myself before but not front-end, always through the itemdatabound method for the child repeater. Is there 100% definitely data in the parent repeater, what do you see when you debug?

Comment: Yeah it's deffo there I can see the value on the page. I just can't seem to access it! On the child repeater though the value is empty....

Comment: Have you tried moving it from the headertemplate to the itemtemplate?

Comment: Hiya, no it doesn't appear in the itemtemplate either!